# @PluginTarget(Node.class) not registering as neo4j plugin

Tags: java, curl, neo4j

Simple class below won't show up as a plugin

```
package com.danmacias.neoneoteplugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.*;
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.*;
//import org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations;

@Description( "An extension to the Neo4j Server for getting all nodes or relationships" )
public class GetPaths extends ServerPlugin
{
  @Name( "breadth_first_paths" )
  @Description( "Breadth First Traversal of a specific node." )
  @PluginTarget( Node.class )
  public Iterable<Path> getPaths( @Source Node graphDb )
  {
    ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    return paths;
  }
}
```

curl returns

```
{                                                                                                                              
  "extensions" : {
    "GetAll" : {
      "get_all_nodes" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/get_all_nodes"
    }
    ...
},
```

But when I replace both instaces of **Node.class** with **GraphDatabaseService.class**, it recognizes the plugin just fine.  Why won't it accept a Node?

*Also, /var/logs/neo4j doesn't show any errors relating to this*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being 100% sure but I think that plugins anchored at node level - by using `@PluginTarget(Node.class)` don't show up at the global extensions. Instead when retrieving a node via REST API there is a `extensions` block as well referring to node based plugins.

Comment: Right you are sir!  Feel like this could be more clearly explained in [Documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html).